# Local inverse/injectivity of a function involving products of $\exp$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function

Applying the inverse function theorem, we can quite easily show that the function
$$ f \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2\quad (x,y)\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x \exp(y) \\ y \exp(x) \end{pmatrix} $$
is locally invertible away from the points where the Jacobian matrix $Df$ is not invertible.
But what about the other points, i.e. those where $xy=1$, lying on the hyperbola $y = \frac{1}{x}$? Is $f$ invertible on a small neighborhood? Or might $f$ even be injective (which I failed to show either)?